# React API calls work in development and fail in production build

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, rest, axios

I'm trying to deploy a React project with a Spring Boot/Hibernate Restful CRUD API. I'm running the SQL database locally and running my React app in development mode (localhost:3000) allows for successful communication with my API.

However, when I built my app for production (localhost:5000), the API is unsuccessful. The API response is an error code 304. My best guess is that something is getting mixed up with the changing ports? It works as intended in development on port :3000 and fails when built on port :5000.

I've never deployed a React app before so thanks for any help!

---

**API call**

```
   const apiCall = () => {
    fileService
      .getUsers()
      .then((response) => {
        setUsers(response.data); //Incorrectly returns a 304 error
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

**getUsers()**

```
    getUsers() {
        return service.getRestClient().get("/api/getAllUsers");
    }
```

**getRestClient()**

```
getRestClient() {
    if (!this.serviceInstance) {
      this.serviceInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/",
        timeout: 10000,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        },
      });
    }
    return this.serviceInstance;
  }
```

Comment: You can't set `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` on a client. This is **response** header that should be provided by a server. Check if your server sends this header if you are going to use your API w/o proxy in production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since posting, I learned that you can't use a proxy in a production version of React. `"proxy:"` in package.json only has an effect in development - not in production. Thanks for everyone's help.

Source: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: Then what is the solution to the problem. I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ben, first of all, I think that you need to sure that your backend really running on 5000 and after that you need to try a simple request using a tool like postman, advanced REST api or insomnia.

perhaps, you need to release the 5000 port on your computer(firewall).

Other ideia is, you need to specify some flags to use other request ip/port, in my case, I use angular and I needed some flags:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```